# problems when increasing the font size in emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

When I increase the font size in emacs to be able to work from distance, the popdown menu goes all whacky. I am using autocomplete. [image]

How can i get rid of this ?

Comment: Did you have any success solving this problem?

Comment: lol that was a long time ago. I don't even use this anymore. I use cedet and it works well. and mostly have shifted to qtcreator. emacs is getting old and uses way too much brain-horsepower which can be used in other important things in life. :)

Comment: All in all,to ans ur Q,I looked for a while and then gave up. Finally found cedet!Try cedet,it works a LOT better than this and has other immensely important features(importing projects). U can disable everything else if ur startup time gets slow or bind a key for starting cedet. That's straight fwd.

http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html

This is a helpful guide for cedet.

...
But as soon as I got comfortable wd qtcreator, I realized how much time I was wasting getting emacs to work rather than create algorithms that actually make a difference in life and happiness...

Comment: Thank you. I use cedet and it is fine. My problem however, is when using Auctex for latex code. I don't have this problem in c++ mode. I happens in Latex mode. I think it is matter of font but I'm sure my font is fixed width. Thanks again for info. CHeers `:)`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an `autocomplete.el` question (it looks like that is the popdown menu you are referring to). Consider reporting the problem/question to the author of that library.